# react nativeのwebviewでlocalのhtmlを読み込む方法を教えてください

Tags: reactjs

`<WebView url='./web/webview.html' style={{flex: 1}} />`
上記のような形で表示したいのですが。。。

Answer (score 1):

ローカルのHTMLは以下のように読み込むことができます。

```
<WebView
  source={require('./helloworld.html')}
/>
```

こちらを参考にしてみてください。
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html